# is exact same object creation possible in different locations in java?

Tags: java

```
Test d1= new Test();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test d1 = new Test();
    System.out.println(d1);
}
```

What happens the same object is created but at different locations .The first one inside a class but outside a method and the second one inside a method of the same  class..is it possible..?? the code compliles fine but at runtime there is some exception like :`atTest<init><Test.java:3>`

Comment: It is not the same object.

Comment: `d != d1` so they are different objects.

Comment: Yes, you'll end up in `stackoverflow error`

Answer (score 3):

> What happens if the same object is created but at different locations?

2 objects create. Perhaps, you cannot create N number of objects like that if you want.

> The first one inside a class but outside a method and the second one inside a method of the same class. Is it possible?

Yes.

The top one  acts as an instance member of `Test` class  and one which you created inside the method is local to that method.

> the code compliles fine but at runtime there is some exception like :at Test

That is stackoverflow error. You are trying to create Test object inside Test class at top level, hence the constructor keep on invoke in recursion and hence the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Test.<init>(Test.java:2)
```

Answer (score 2):

you are recursively creating a new instance of `Test` until your are out of memory.

so let's look at it step by step:

in `main` method you have:

```
 Test d1 = new Test();
```

this will create a new instance `Test`, which consequently on the initialization of `Test`, you create a new variable:

```
Test d = new Test();
```

so new object is created, but same as before you are creating a new instance of `Test` again, which again creates a new instance of `Test`:

```
Test d = new Test();
```

this will happen indefinitely until ran out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes , The above code is valid and 2 different objects are created in
>   memory

```
class Test{
   Test d = new Test();  // instance object

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test d1 = new Test(); // local to this method
    System.out.println(d1);
  }
}
```

Also as suggested by @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ , it produces `java.lang.StackOverflowError` due to object creation at the top level